# How can variable be used before anything is assigned to it?

Tags: haskell

I have this code, from a website:

```
doGuessing num = do
   putStrLn "Enter your guess:"
   guess <- getLine
   case (read guess) `compare` num of
     LT -> do putStrLn "Too low!"
              doGuessing num
     GT -> do putStrLn "Too high!"
              doGuessing num
     EQ -> putStrLn "You Win!"
```

And I am wondering, how can `num` be compared if nothing is assigned to it yet?

Comment: Indent your code properly. How do you expect other people to read it?!

Comment: i got this code off this website and im trying to learn haskell, it looks indented properly to me...

Comment: By the way, there is no concept of "first" assigning something to a variable and "then" using it later.

Answer (score 4):

`doGuessing` is a function with a single parameter called `num`. This is equivalent to something like:

```
function doGuessing(num) {
    ...
}
```

in an imperative language.

Thus `num` will be bound to a value when you actually use the `doGuessing` function you defined.

To use the function, you can put it in `main` with an argument:

```
main = doGuessing 10
```

In general, in Haskell `f 1 2 3` is the same as `f(1,2,3)` in c-like languages.

Comment: so how do i call this function with an argument, say 4?

Answer (score 3):

```
doGuessing :: (Ord a, Read a) => a -> IO ()
```

In general, values are bound in Haskell, not assigned. That function uses the do syntax for monadic processing to resemble an imperative style. Still, until you pass it an argument it remains a function, not an action.

An example of calling it might be:

```
main :: IO ()
main = doGuessing 4
```

Comment: Simply put the arguments after the function name. Haskell will only evaluate things that are used, though; for standalone programs, it evaluates the main function.